# tensorflow: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: tensorflow

I am playing with the fixed code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311893/how-can-i-train-a-simple-non-linear-regression-model-with-tensor-flow). I am getting the above error. Googling suggests it might be some kind of dimension mismatch, though my diagnostics does not show any:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (_x_, _y_) in getb(train_X, train_Y):
            print("y data raw", _y_.shape )
            _y_ = tf.reshape(_y_, [-1, 1])
            print( "y data ", _y_.get_shape().as_list())
            print("y place holder", yy.get_shape().as_list())

            print("x data", _x_.shape )            
            print("x place holder", xx.get_shape().as_list() )

            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={xx: _x_, yy: _y_})
```

Looking at the dimensions, everything is alright:

```
y data raw (20,)
y data  [20, 1]
y place holder [20, 1]

x data (20, 10)
x place holder [20, 10]
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-00e0bdc140b2> in <module>()
     16             print("x place holder", xx.get_shape().as_list() )
     17 
---> 18             sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={xx: _x_, yy: _y_})
     19 
     20 #         # Display logs per epoch step

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict)
    355             e.args = (e.message,)
    356             raise e
--> 357           np_val = np.array(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_t.dtype.as_numpy_dtype)
    358           if subfeed_t.op.type == 'Placeholder':
    359             if not subfeed_t.get_shape().is_compatible_with(np_val.shape):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any debugging tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This—not very helpful—error is raised when one of the values in the `feed_dict` argument to [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) is a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) object (in this case, the result of [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape)).

The values in `feed_dict` must be numpy arrays, or some value `x` that can be implicitly converted to a numpy array using [`numpy.array(x)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). `tf.Tensor` objects cannot be *implicitly* converted, because doing so might require a lot of work: instead you have to call `sess.run(t)` to convert a tensor `t` to a numpy array.

As you noticed in your answer, using `np.reshape(_y_, [-1, 1])` works, because it produces a numpy array (and because `_y_` is a numpy array to begin with). In general, you should always prepare data to be fed using numpy and other pure-Python operations.

Answer (score 0):

replacing `tf` reshape with plain `numpy` one helped:

```
        _y_ = np.reshape(_y_, [-1, 1])
```

the actual reason why is still unclear, but it works.